# JavaScript convert String to json array, but a get array of each character from string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I try to convert a string to json array in javaScript, but i can not. Here is my code:

```
var strImg = "[{"a":"bc","b":"gh},{"a":"bc","b":"bc"}]";
var images = JSON.parse(strImg);
```

but i only get a array of each character of strImg;
when i call: `console.log(images[0]); it return "[";`
i do not know how to do with this.
Thank for any help.

Comment: Do you originally escape double quotes? This way, it is not a valid code at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be that you are using only `"` instead of both `"` and `'`.

```
var strImg = "[{"a":"bc","b":"gh},{"a":"bc","b":"bc"}]";
var images = JSON.parse(strImg);
```

Try:

```
var strImg = '[{"a":"bc","b":"gh},{"a":"bc","b":"bc"}]';
var images = JSON.parse(strImg);
```

Now, `'` represent the whole string and it is not more divide between wrong substrings. (Note how the **red text** is in the post).

Comment: I understand why. My json array is already a string. When saving data, I used the `Gson (). tojson ()` function again. so there was an error. Very thank you. Thanks to you, I have paid attention to this detail.

Answer (score 0):

Your "string" doesn't look like a string.

```
> JSON.parse('[{"a":"bc","b":"gh"},{"a": "bc","b": "bc"}]');
< [{a: "bc", b: "gh"}, {a: "bc", b: "bc"}] (2)
```

You need to escape your quotes inside a string or use different quotes...

P.S.
You can also use something like https://jsonlint.com to validate your JSON for missing symbols.

Comment: Thanks. Because my json array is already a string. When saving data, I used the `Gson (). tojson()` function again. so there was an error.